# How to avoid geopy time out problem with nominatim?

Tags: python, timeout, geopy, nominatim

I am using geopy with nominatim to get cities names from geographic coordinates.
I am using the below code :

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim 
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="class-app")
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    georeverse = geolocator.reverse
    locationdep = georeverse(row[3],language='fr-FR',exactly_one=True)
    address = location.raw['address']
    state=address.get('state','')
    town=address.get('town','')
```

My problem is that it throws a time out error after treating 256 rows and my data frame contain over 100 000 rows.
So how would I handle this to avoid the timeout error?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value for time out in `Nominatim` for example...

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="class-app", timeout=10)
```

hope this does job..

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, it is taking even more time with the timeout and it stops throwing a time out error.